# Add meta box to categories admin panel in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress theme and I need to add a meta box (checkbox) to the category admin panel.
I've written the code to add the meta box to the panel but there is 2 problems:
1- First it appears below the "Add category button" 
2- What functions should I use to save the checkbox value in the database ?

and there is the code to add the checkbox

```
add_action ( 'category_add_form_fileds', 'add_to_main_page');
add_action('category_edit_form', 'add_to_main_page');
function add_to_main_page() {
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="add_to_main" id="add_to_main" value="1">
<label for="add_to_main">This category on main page</label>
<?php }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After fixing one typo—"category_add_form_fileds" to "category_add_form_fields"—your code worked fine for me. I get a checkbox on both forms above the "Add New Category" / "Update" buttons. This is a complete version and should do the trick:

```
add_action( 'category_add_form_fields', 'add_to_mainpg_fields' );
add_action( 'category_edit_form', 'add_to_mainpg_fields' );
function add_to_mainpg_fields() {
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="add_to_main" id="add_to_main" value="1" />
    <label for="add_to_main">This category on main page</label>
<?php
}

add_action( 'created_category', 'add_to_mainpg_save' );
add_action( 'edited_category', 'add_to_mainpg_save' );
function add_to_mainpg_save( $term_id ) {
    if( !isset( $_POST['add_to_main'] ) )
        return;

    $stickies = get_option( 'main_page_cats' );

    if( !is_array( $stickies ) )
        $stickies = array( $term_id );

    if( !in_array( $term_id, $stickies ) )
        $stickies[] = $term_id;

    update_option( 'main_page_cats', $stickies );
}
```

This is a modified version of the `stick_post` function used for sticky posts.

[This tutorial](http://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-category-extra-fields/) is instructive for saving multiple options. Two robust solutions are [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-category-meta/) and [this library](http://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/). I understand if you don't want all that for a single field, but others might. :)